# Можно ли сказать "состоялось событие"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

Написала сперва, а потом засомневалась: а можно ли сказать, что событие состоялось? Или лучше все-таки "случилось"? А если "состоялось", тогда что будет лучше?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Событие  определяется как  значительное явление, факт в личной или общественной жизни. Слово сочетается только с определенными глаголами:

1. Событие ПРОИЗОШЛО – это нейтральное значение, нейтральный стиль;  события, которые происходят,  обычно отражают объективное и объяснимое течение жизни.
2. Событие СЛУЧИЛОСЬ – здесь уже присутствует  элемент неожиданности, непредсказуемости.
3. Событие СВЕРШИЛОСЬ  –  так говорят об очень значимых событиях, стиль книжный.

А вот СОСТОЯТЬСЯ или ОСУЩЕСТВИТЬСЯ событие не может, зато может состояться заранее запланированное мероприятие (собрание, концерт)  или осуществиться мечта.

Причину такой сочетаемости следует искать в этимологии слов. Событие – это то, что сбылось, стало реальностью, но событием НЕЛЬЗЯ УПРАВЛЯТЬ: оно происходит  или случается  (свершается) без прямого влияния человека (философы считают, что материальными становятся такие события, которые требуют минимальных затрат энергии). А то, что осуществилось или состоялось, уже  имело прообраз в виде идеи, которая и воплотилась в жизнь.

ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ.
Этимология слова «случиться»: соотносится с др.-рус. "лучаи" - судьба, сравнить:лучший, благополучие, случай.

Answer (score 2):

Согласно "Словарю сочетаемости слов" Института русского языка событие *происходит* или *случается*. Если имеется в виду запланированное мероприятие, то такое событие происходит. Состояться может что-то более конкретное: фестиваль, концерт, спектакль, открытие или закрытие чего-либо.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, со словом "событие" обычно употребляют глагол "произошло"

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте! Думаю так, если вам самой не нравиться, значит не понравится и другим. Вообще, событие - это со бытиё, нечто сопутствующее бытию, происходящее. А состоявшееся - это нечто состоящее, т.е. что-то конкретное, из чего может состоять событие.

Answer (score 1):

Благодаря малограмотным переводчикам, которые неизменно переводят английское "event" как "событие", тогда как это слово может означать еще и "мероприятие" и даже "соревнование", по нашему ТВ часто вещают о спортивных событиях, культурных событиях (фестивалях, концертах, спектаклях). А в таком значении у этого слова возможны совсем другие контексты.